# AppleScript: Multiple "set theText to replaceText"

Tags: applescript

this is basically my first AppleScript ever since I never learned scripting/programming ;)
But I was able to make it work but it doesn't seem optimal since it crashes occassionally and I expect a better performance (speedwise) when all these single commands are put in one bucket:
I want to combine several "set theText to replaceText" rows. But I can't make it work.

[This works (even though it's not super clean/easy optimised)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb04X.png)

```
Run AppleScript:

on replaceText(find, replace, textString)
set prevTIDs to AppleScript‘s text item delimiters
set AppleScript‘s text item delimiters to find
set textString to text items of textString
set AppleScript‘s text item delimiters to replace
set textString to „“ & textString
set AppleScript‘s text item delimiters to prevTIDs
return textString
end replaceText

on run {input}
set theText to replaceText(„ABC“, „CBA“, input as string)
end run

Run AppleScript:

on replaceText(find, replace, textString)
set prevTIDs to AppleScript‘s text item delimiters
set AppleScript‘s text item delimiters to find
set textString to text items of textString
set AppleScript‘s text item delimiters to replace
set textString to „“ & textString
set AppleScript‘s text item delimiters to prevTIDs
return textString
end replaceText

on run {input}
set theText to replaceText(" ", "", input as string)
end run
```

[This doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr2DB.png)

```
Run AppleScript:

on replaceText(find, replace, textString)
set prevTIDs to AppleScript‘s text item delimiters
set AppleScript‘s text item delimiters to find
set textString to text items of textString
set AppleScript‘s text item delimiters to replace
set textString to „“ & textString
set AppleScript‘s text item delimiters to prevTIDs
return textString
end replaceText

on run {input}
set theText to replaceText(„ABC“, „CBA“, input as string)
set theText to replaceText(" ", "", input as string)
end run
```

I tried to put all "set theText to replaceText" under each other, also tried with "else" or delays in between but it didn't work at all.

The main purpose of my script is the following:

1. Take the selected text from any programm (path to a file)
2. Modify the selected text accordingly (Mac <-> Windows path structure)
3. Copy the text to Clipboard and open the folder /file with finder (Mac OS)

Answer (score 0):

First of all this cannot work anyway because double quotes must be `character id 34` (`"`) and single quotes `character id 39` (`'`).

The error is a typo. To apply the second find/replace call to the result of the first you have to replace `input as string` with `theText` in the second line. I renamed the variables to make it clear.

And `AppleScript's` is only necessary if changing the text item delimiters is inside an application `tell` block.

```
on replaceText(find, replace, textString)
    set prevTIDs to text item delimiters
    set text item delimiters to find
    set textItems to text items of textString
    set text item delimiters to replace
    set textString to textItems as text
    set text item delimiters to prevTIDs
    return textString
end replaceText

on run {input}
    set firstReplace to replaceText("ABC", "CBA", input as string)
    set secondReplace to replaceText(space, "", firstReplace)
    return secondReplace
end run
```